# Unlink files inside fs.watch in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way or package that allows me to watch for new files and delete them?
Even if i try to delete files in sub directories. i get errors because the file is locked.

```
fs.watch(example, function (eventType, filename) {
   fs.unlink("example/"+filename+"/testfile", (err) => {
     if (err) throw err;
       console.log('successfully deleted');
   }); 
});
```

Appreciate your time

Comment: So you’re trying to watch before such a file exists, then notice it on creation, then delete it? If so, you may want your create function (whatever that is) to notify the watcher after creating a file, so it can add it to the watch list. Hope that helps. I’m on a plane, otherwise I’d jump into the docs. Interesting problem here.

Comment: @BenSteward  i want to watch for new foldersand if a new folder appears i want to execute a node module functions on the new folder. The function will create a new file inside the new folder and afterwards delete it, which causes an error because after the file is created it is locked by the fs.watch command and you cant use the unlink command on it.

Comment: Interesting. Can you call `.unwatch()` (or some equivalent) before unlinking?

Comment: @BenSteward Yes that works, however if i close the watcher before executing my function i cant detect if a new folder will be added during the time the watcher is closed

Comment: Ah yes, I meant to unwatch only the file you want to delete. I thought I remembered seeing that in the docs. Doesn’t stop the watcher, just releases the specified file.